# Android - Encrypting/Protecting SD Card Content

Tags: android, encryption, password-protection, sd-card

I have an application which writes and reads from a specific file on the SD card.

What i would like is a way to encrypt the whole SD card or a minimum of That specific folder. So if the phone is stolen no one can read the content of that folder.

However, i also want the application to still be able to interact with the folder and the password isn't required until someone looks at the folder specifically (using astro etc) or inserts it into a PC to view.

Is this possible? thanks

Comment: can we protect SD card folder. if can you provide sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do this manually, look into [javax.crypto](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html) for getting the crypto bit done relatively painlessly.

Comment: Also this may cause some issues, because then if i connect sd card to pc i would not be able to see the files unless i unencrypt them on the pc if thats possable

Comment: i have encrypted the file, but then i can not open on my pc

Comment: Also this means everytime i need to use the file within my application i have to decrypt it and then encrypt it again

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible with an ordinary (unmodified) android system (I assume).

If you are talking about your own app - you could implement your own file level encryption in your application.

For everything else, I'd say you need to modify android to include some kind of encrypted file system and the relevant UI for it.

Comment: Ok thanks, im new to this as you can see....How do i implement my own file level encryption as you said? and erm what does this mean?